# I get the following error: not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' in Mysql WorkBench with a simple script

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Even with this simple script or any other:

```
CREATE DATABASE Oscar 2 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_es_trad_0900_ai_ci;
```

---

The Script is `UTF-8` text.

When I run the script in any tab in workbench, it works fine

I hope the scripts works with "Run SQL Script"

Comment: ' hope the scripts works with "Run SQL Script"' - please elaborate.

Comment: Where do you see "NoneType"?